# Form validation and mysql database connection

Tags: php, mysql, forms, database-connection

I'm working on a project (PHP/MySQL) , but i have a problem in the validation of a from data.
when i submit the information , i did not find it in my database ( PHPmyadmin ).i think it's a connection problem ! 
here is my form :

```
<form id="formulaire" role="form" action="index.php" method="POST">
                    <h3 style="color:red;">Ajouter un reservoir</h3>
                    <label for="coordlat" style="margin-bottom:7px;">Latitude du point</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="latitude" name="latitude" placeholder="Latitude"  style="margin-bottom:7px;" required>
                    <label for="coordlng" style="margin-bottom:7px;">Longitude de point</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="longitude" name="longitude"  placeholder="Longitude" style="margin-bottom:7px;" required>
                    <label for="coordlng" style="margin-bottom:7px;">Code du reservoir</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="coderes" name="coderes" placeholder="Code" style="margin-bottom:7px;" required>
                    <label for="coordlng" style="margin-bottom:7px;">Nom du reservoir</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nomres" name="nomres"  placeholder="Nom" style="margin-bottom:7px;" required>
                    <label for="coordlng" style="margin-bottom:7px;">Adress du reservoir</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="adressres" name="adressres"  placeholder="Adress" style="margin-bottom:7px;" required>
                    <label for="coordlng" style="margin-bottom:7px;">Capacité du reservoir</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="capaciteres" name="capaciteres"  placeholder="Capacité" style="margin-bottom:7px;" required>
                    <label for="coordlng" style="margin-bottom:7px;">Alimentation</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="alimentationres" name="alimentationres"  placeholder="Alimentation" style="margin-bottom:7px;" required>
                    <label for="coordlng" style="margin-bottom:7px;">Cote radial du reservoir</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="coteradres" name="coteradres"  placeholder="Cote radial" style="margin-bottom:7px;" required>
                    <div style="padding-top:10px;">
                        <select name="typeres" style="margin-bottom:7px;" required>
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Type du reservoir</option>
                                <option value="enterre">Enterré</option>
                                <option value="semi-enterre">Semi enterré</option>
                        </select>
                        <select name="pseutype" style="margin-bottom:7px;" required>
                                <option value="" disabled selected>Pseudo-type du reservoir</option>
                                <option value="onep">Reservoir ONEP</option>
                                <option value="ramsa">Reservoir RAMSA</option>
                                <option value="onep">Forage C</option>
                                <option value="onep">Forage RA</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div style="padding-top:10px;">
                        <input type="submit" value="Valider" id="Reservoirbtn" class="btn btn-success" >
                        <input type="reset" value="Vider es champs" id="Reservoirbtn" class="btn btn-danger"   style="margin-left:25px;">
                    </div>
            </form>
```

and here is my php code to insert a new record in my database :

```
    <?php
  $connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mydb");

  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo ("Échec de la connexion : %s\n" . mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}


    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$query = " INSERT INTO 'reservoir' (Code_reservoir, nom_reservoir, adress_reservoir, latitude, longtitude, capacite, cote_radial, espace, pseudo_espace, alimentation)
           VALUES ('$_POST[coderes]', '$_POST[nomres]', '$_POST[adressres]', '$_POST[latitude]', '$_POST[longitude]', '$_POST[capaciteres]', '$_POST[coteradres]', '$_POST[typeres]','$_POST[pseutype]', '$_POST[alimentationres]')";

mysql_query($query,$connect);
mysql_close($connect);
}          

?>
```

Please HELP :) Thanks

Comment: try mysqli_error($connect) to get the last error and by the way the post variables have to be connected with the rest of the query like this: "VALUES ('" . $_POST[coderes] . "' and so on..

Comment: Thanks Thulur for your respond ! please can you write me the query ! i'm a little bit confused about that !

Comment: Sorry but that should be your task ;)

Comment: Exactly ! what about this one : $query = " INSERT INTO 'reservoir' (Code_reservoir, nom_reservoir, adress_reservoir, latitude, longtitude, capacite, cote_radial, espace, pseudo_espace, alimentation)
           VALUES ('$_POST[coderes]', '$_POST[nomres]', '$_POST[adressres]', '$_POST[latitude]', '$_POST[longitude]', '$_POST[capaciteres]', '$_POST[coteradres]', '$_POST[typeres]','$_POST[pseutype]', '$_POST[alimentationres]')";

Comment: @SalasDesign what is the problem with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think the mistake is that you have not selected the database.

Try this:

```
<?php
      $connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mydb");
    
      if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo ("Échec de la connexion : %s\n" . mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db("//database name", $connect);

if (!$db_selected)
  {
  die ("Can\'t use this databse : " . mysqli_error());
  }
    
    
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    
    $query = " INSERT INTO 'reservoir' (Code_reservoir, nom_reservoir, adress_reservoir, latitude, longtitude, capacite, cote_radial, espace, pseudo_espace, alimentation)
               VALUES ('$_POST[coderes]', '$_POST[nomres]', '$_POST[adressres]', '$_POST[latitude]', '$_POST[longitude]', '$_POST[capaciteres]', '$_POST[coteradres]', '$_POST[typeres]','$_POST[pseutype]', '$_POST[alimentationres]')";
    
    mysql_query($query,$connect);
    mysql_close($connect);
    }          
    
    ?>
```

more help can be found from this link: [mysqli_select_db](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_select_db.asp)

I'm not sure but hope this will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot my dude for you respond ! But i fixed my problem by myself , it was a little syntax problem

Comment: @SalasDesign ok...but why did you remove 'accepted' mark on my answer?I want only the reason(faults in the answer or tell me if it didn't help etc).

Comment: Actually i tried to use the code in your answer , but i didn't get what i want ! but i really appreciate your contribution :D

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest method you can use to pass many values from a html form to database is shown below. But you need to care about something like..

1.must use a name for input type submit : you can replace your submit line in form with this

```
<input type="submit" value="Valider" id="Reservoirbtn" class="btn btn-success" name="submit_form">
```

2.you need to use database table field names as same as the name used in the html form input names. ie,table column names must be latitude,longitude,coderes,etc...

if you think your code  have only connection problem. you can use  connect statements from below code,displaying respective connection error (lines 1-7)

php code

```
<?php
define(“DBHOST”,”localhost”);
define(“DBUNAME”,”root”);
define(“DBPASSWORD”,””);
define(“DBNAME”,”mydb”);
mysql_connect(DBHOST,DBUNAME,DBPASSWORD)or die(‘cant connect to DB’);
mysql_select_db(DBNAME)or die(“cant select db”);
$inputs = array();
$skip_input=array(‘submit_form’);
$error =array();
if(isset($_POST['submit_form']))
{
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
{
if(!in_array($key,$skip_input))
{
$inputs[$key] =$value;
}
}
}
$fieldValues = implode(“‘,’”,array_values($inputs));
$table = ‘reservoir’;
$sql=”INSERT INTO $table VALUES (‘$fieldValues’)”;
mysql_query($sql);
echo “inserted successfully”;
?>
```